# Post method not adding values in database table Asp.net mvc web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I created a Post Action in visual studio MVC Web API and passed tbl_employee in Parameter and when i am checking my Action via Postman it's inserting null values to my table in database.

working on visual studio 2019 and framework version is 4.5.

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]tbl_employee stbl_Employee)
        {              
            try
            {  
                se.tbl_employee.Add(stbl_Employee);
                se.SaveChanges();
                var message = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, 
                stbl_Employee);
                message.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri + 
                stbl_Employee.emp_id.ToString());
                return message;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
           return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,ex);

            }
        }  


 public partial class tbl_employee        
    {
        public int emp_id { get; set; }
        public string emp_name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> emp_salary { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> emp_department { get; set; }

        public virtual tbl_department tbl_department { get; set; }
    }
```

The output is all values are null in database and postman is giving error.

Comment: What is the error? If the code throws, it won't save anything. The error will tell you what's wrong. Debug your code and check what's going on when the exception is thrown

Answer (score 0):

I would check the format of the JSON or XML you are sending to your endpoint via Postman.  It sounds like you might have a problem with deserializing the body of your HTTP request.

It might be worth looking into add [Swagger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger?view=aspnetcore-3.0) to your project to help you check the formats and test the api